# SOLR - Boost Function Not Working As Expected

Tags: solr, sunspot

I have the following boost function which is supposed to add a boost between 0 and 1,000 depending on how recent the `updated_at` field is (more recent would get more boost). Anything older than 1 month will get 0 boost. The problem is that it does not seem be changing the result set regardless of what's in the `updated_at` field.

```
bf = recip(ms(NOW,updated_at_dt),43.2e-11,1,1)^1000.0
```

Is something wrong with the function?

Comment: how does your complete query look?

Comment: I do a keyword search for a field that's boosted 100. I noticed that I need to increase the boost function from `^1000.0` to about `^100000.0` to have the effect I need.

Comment: Remember that this will start to deviate from 1 as soon as 1 ms has passed. See the formula for how recip works (and what the values actually mean).